# What is the meaning of with?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-meaning

meaning of "with" in this sentence?

"2 bathrooms with one in each bedroom"

"with" has many meanings.. I do not know which it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are two bathrooms with one in each bedroom.

simply means

> There are two bedrooms. Each bedroom has a (separate) bathroom.

*With something* means *including or having something*.

> A bedroom with a bathroom

Here’s a nice contemporary bedroom **with** an attached glass bathroom:

[image]

Here’s a hotel-like bedroom **with** a freestanding bathtub:

[image]